# SQL Server Data Tools 2010 Measures Grid Values Not Showing

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas

I'm developing a BISM Tabular Model in SQL Server Analysis Services (SP1).  The tool I'm using is SQL Server Data Tools 2010 (the 2012 Version doesn't exist / work yet).  My data source is a SQL Server 2012 SP1 Relational Instance

In the measures grid the results of the DAX expressions, i.e. the Measure's value, are now not being displayed. They did before. I'm not sure what I did.

An example.  Say create a measure using DAX like:

Users:=DISTINCTCOUNT(UserId) // Say I have 50 UserIds

The measures grid should display

Users: 50

But it just displays:

Users

It doesn't appear to affect other any other functionality

Any Ideas? Thanks